# getWritableDatabase returns null

Tags: android, sqlite

I have Android service, that uses SQLite database. I faced some troubles with database initialization.

I have class DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public boolean db_loaded=false;
public DBHelper() {
    super(ContextBean.getLocalContext(), "resplugin1.db", null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table tasks ("
            + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "title text);");
    db_loaded=true;
}
```

I have client class that uses it:

```
public class DataProvider {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DBHelper dbHelper;

public DataProvider(){
    dbHelper=new DBHelper();
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
public void close(){
    dbHelper.close();
}
public TaskDescriptor getTaskById(int id){
    while(dbHelper.db_loaded==false){}
    String[] args={Integer.toString(id)};
    if(database==null){
        Log.d("ResPluginService1","DATABASE IS NULL");
    }
/*...*/
}
```

The problem is that database object is always **NULL**. 
*getWritableDatabase* method throws no exceptions, it just returns null. What can cause so strange behaviour?

Comment: The `db_loaded` flag and busy-waiting on it is completely wrong. `getWritableDatabase()` always returns a database or throws an exception. Have you overridden the method yourself?

Comment: put your execSQL inside a try catch and do some log ?

Comment: 1. I have not overriden getWritableDatabase myself
2.I have put both getWritableDatabase and execSQL in `try-catch` but I got nothing, Also I mentioned that database is created, after executing this command I can see in app properties that some data appears

Comment: DId you find a solution for this? I am having the same problem. When I surround the call to  `getWritableDatabase()` with try/catch, it shows an NPE