# SQLite getwritableDatabase returns null

Tags: android, sqlite

While trying to develop some unit tests for the project that I'm working on I hit a wall where I need to test DB-behaviour.
I'm trying to create a in-memory DB(SQLite)

While I thought that this rather basic test would do as asked, it always returns a NULL database, which is not what I expected.

```
package be.wgkovl.evdt.Util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.test.mock.MockContext;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith( PowerMockRunner.class )
public class ClassForStack {


    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Context context;

    private Cursor test() {
        if (db != null) {
            return db.rawQuery("Select * from myTable", new String[]{});
        } else {
            System.out.println("Db is null :-(");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String[] emtpyArgument = new String[]{};


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("Setting up");
        context = new MockContext();

        SQLiteOpenHelper dummy = new SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "SomeName.memory", null, 1) {
            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            }
        };


        String basicInitQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC, value TEXT)";
        String basicInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable(id, value) VALUES (1,?)";
        db = dummy.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Test
    public void baseDbTest() {
        Cursor c = test();
        if (c != null) {
            System.out.println(c.getColumnNames());
            System.out.println(c.getColumnCount());
            System.out.println("Starting test");
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at several different solutions on Stackoverflow, but none seemed to be able to point me to the right solution. They are listed here

[getWritableDatabase returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488869/getwritabledatabase-returns-null)
[Android Sqlite always null even after calling getWritableDatabase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414143/android-sqlite-always-null-even-after-calling-getwritabledatabase)
[Create SQLite database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037767/create-sqlite-database-in-android)
[SQLite getReadableDatabase() returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141706/sqlite-getreadabledatabase-returns-null)
[SQLiteOpenHelper failing to call onCreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024223/sqliteopenhelper-failing-to-call-oncreate)

What am I doing wrong that I get a null db, but not any kind of error or exception?

Comment: Just to confirm, is this a connected test defined in `/androidTest`?

Comment: what do you mean connected test? It is currently in the designated test folder in my structure.

Comment: There are two test folders under `src/` - `src/test` which contains JUnit tests that are [run on your local machine](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests), and `src/androidTest` which runs unit tests [on a connected Android device](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests). You cannot use Android-specific classes in the `src/test` folder (in your case, `Cursor`, `Context` and `SQLiteOpenHelper`). I suspect this is why you're getting `null` in return.

Comment: it should be able to run those tests locally. What use is a mockContext if not for local tests?

Comment: But your entire test is dependent on `SQLiteOpenHelper`, is it not?

Comment: that is indeed the case. is there a local alternative for that one?(is cursor device only? I thought that was just a DB result)

Comment: For now, see if you can recreate this test [as an instrumented test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests) and see what happens when you run it on a device or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to create the table inside onCreate()?

```
  db.execSQL(basicInitQuery);
```

Comment: as far as I see, the onCreate() isn't triggered. It does not show my logging in any case..

Comment: how else would the table be created?

Comment: in a function that you call later. if you need to define the entirety of your database in the onCreate, it should give an exception if you do nothing there, instead of a null database object.

Comment: I have tried it yes, it didn't seem to work. Since I'm at home now, It'll have to wait for tomorrow untill I can try againt